# How to replace JTextField as filter with string in GlazedList?

Tags: java, swing, filter, jtable, glazedlists

I have a set of radio button which i want to use as filter for my table. this radio button sets a variable in my model class. With a getter in my model i retrieve this value and i want to use this value as filter in my GlazedList table.

**Does any body know how to do it?**

Below is my table with JTextField as filter:

```
TextFilterator<Barcode> barcodeFilterator = new TextFilterator<Barcode>() { ... };
    WebTextField searchField = new WebTextField(barcodeModel.getSelectedFilter());
    MatcherEditor<Barcode> textMatcherEditor = new TextComponentMatcherEditor<Barcode>(searchField, barcodeFilterator);
    FilterList<Barcode> filterList = new FilterList<Barcode>(BarcodeUtil.retrieveBarcodeEventList(files), textMatcherEditor);
    TableFormat<Barcode> tableFormat = new TableFormat<Barcode>() { .... };
    EventTableModel<Barcode> tableModel = new EventTableModel<Barcode>(filterList, tableFormat);
    barcodeTable.setModel(tableModel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would point you to the [Custom MatcherEditor screencast](http://publicobject.com/glazedlistsdeveloper/screencasts/custommatchereditor/) as a good reference to implementing your own `Matcher`s to cope with filtering from a set of options.

The key part is the creation of a `MatcherEditor`, in this instance it's filtering a table of people by nationality.

```
private static class NationalityMatcherEditor extends AbstractMatcherEditor implements ActionListener {
    private JComboBox nationalityChooser;

    public NationalityMatcherEditor() {
        this.nationalityChooser = new JComboBox(new Object[] {"British", "American"});
        this.nationalityChooser.getModel().setSelectedItem("Filter by Nationality...");
        this.nationalityChooser.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public Component getComponent() {
        return this.nationalityChooser;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        final String nationality = (String) this.nationalityChooser.getSelectedItem();
        if (nationality == null)
            this.fireMatchAll();
        else
            this.fireChanged(new NationalityMatcher(nationality));
    }

    private static class NationalityMatcher implements Matcher {
        private final String nationality;

        public NationalityMatcher(String nationality) {
            this.nationality = nationality;
        }

        public boolean matches(Object item) {
            final AmericanIdol idol = (AmericanIdol) item;
            return this.nationality.equals(idol.getNationality());
        }
    }
}
```

How this `MatcherEditor` is used shouldn't be too unfamiliar as it's similar to `TextMatcherEditor`s:

```
EventList idols = new BasicEventList();
NationalityMatcherEditor nationalityMatcherEditor = new NationalityMatcherEditor();
FilterList filteredIdols = new FilterList(idols, nationalityMatcherEditor);
```

In the above sample the `JComboBox` is declared and initiated in the `MatcherEditor` itself. You need not follow that style exactly, although you need a reference to the object you're tracking. For me, if I'm watching Swing controls I tend to declare and initiate with the rest of the form and then pass a reference in, e.g.

```
....
private JComboBox nationalityChooser;
public NationalityMatcherEditor(JComboBox alreadyConfiguredComboBox) {
    this.nationalityChooser = alreadyConfiguredComboBox;
}
....
```